# Reducing PNG file size with pyvips: matching ImgBot and ImageMagick optimizations

Tags: python, png, vips

I'm trying to minimize file size of PNG images written with `pyvips.Image.pngsave()`. Original files written with just `.pngsave(output)` are at https://github.com/CDDA-Tilesets/UltimateCataclysm and we'll look at `giant.png` which is `119536` bytes.

[ImgBot was able to reduce file size](https://github.com/UmbralReaper/UltimateCataclysm/pull/1/files) to `50672`.

[pngsave(output, compression=9, palette=True, strip=True)](https://github.com/CleverRaven/Cataclysm-DDA/pull/47453) to `58722`

But the `convert` command from ImageMagick is still able to reduce file size further after the latter, to `42833` with default options:

```sh
$ convert giant_pyvips_c9.png giant_pyvips_magick.png
```

The question is whether it's possible to fit the same image into `42833` bytes using only `pyvips` to avoid adding another step to our workflow?

#### Update: Warning

`palette` size is [limited to 256 colors](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter08.html#png.ch08.div.5.1) and `pyvips` doesn't warn you if conversion becomes lossy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try turning off filtering:

```
$ vips copy giant.png x.png[palette,compression=9,strip,filter=0]
$ ls -l x.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john 41147 Feb 14 10:58 x.png
```

Background: PNG filters put the image though a difference filter before compression. Compressing differences to neighbouring pixels rather than absolute pixel values can boost the compression ratio if there is some local pattern in values. pyvips uses an adaptive filter by default.

Palette images encode an index into a look up table rather than anything related to luminance, so there is much less local correlation. In this case, filtering actually hurts compression.

http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Filters.html

You can see the values allowed for the `filter=` parameter here:

https://github.com/libvips/libvips/blob/master/libvips/include/vips/foreign.h#L579-L598

**Update** libvips 8.13 changed the default filter to `none` since it gives better results for most images. libvips 8.15 added support for named flags (finally), so you can use eg. `paeth` or `up|sub` instead of numbers, if you want.

Comment: Thank you again :) I'll try it later today

Comment: I tweaked git master libvips to default filter to off for pngsave of palette images. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: I had the best results on `normal.png` there with `filter=8` whatever that is